# Fullpage-Caching and Magento\Customer\Model\Session in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, session, full-page-cache

I would like to add a Block with different content when user is logged in or not. Content depends *not* on customer-data - just logged-in state.

```
class Grouped extends \Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped
{
    protected $customerSession;


    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils $arrayUtils,
       array $data,
       \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    )
    {
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
        parent::__construct($context, $arrayUtils, $data);
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        return $this->customerSession->isLoggedIn();
    }

}
```

In my phtml-File a just call `$this->isLoggedIn()` but it is always "false" when fullpage-cache is enabled.

How I could get information about customer-logged-in-state when fullpage cache is enabled on product-view page? How I prevent it from caching or adding two different caching-tags? (not-logged-in or logged-in) I believed in `$this->_isScopePrivate` but doesn't help..

Pricing, which depends on customer-group, works well on product-view page but don't find any informations why.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, answering myself is a little bit ridiculous.

`getChackeKeyInfo` is only relevant for `block-caching`, `fullpage-caching` looks different :(

In case of depending on **Customer\Session isLoggedIn is always "false"**. Same when cache is clean before calling product-view.

But

Instead of depending on `Customer\Session` I copied some code `auf Review Module`. It depends on `\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext.`

In this case I'm able to distinguish logged in or not by calling

```
$httpContent->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
```

Would be great to get some explanation why :)

Comment: just curious: is a cache key change not working at all with fpc? Was hoping for some automatic hole punching, but did not look into this yet

Comment: far shot on your question: I assume the http context considers a cookie set if the user is logged in

Comment: cool decision. helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

the isScopePrivate switch sounds reasonable at first, but it seems not to be considered in the cache key generation: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php#L967

adding the customer group to the cache key by overriding the getCacheKeyInfo method should do the trick in your case:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php#L957